# Does pure iron not rust?

Tags: metal, transition-metals

In my school science textbook, written more than twenty years ago, it said that *pure* iron does not rust. Accompanying was a photograph of an ancient iron statue situated outside, which had not rusted.

Is this correct?

Comment: Related: [Is there pure iron in nature?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/115367) As for the [statue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_pillar_of_Delhi#Scientific_analysis), it's by no means made of *pure* iron and is protected by passivation. Meteorite iron is also not chemically pure and typically contains nickel.

Answer (score 4):

The purity of the iron is less important here than the conditions of the atmosphere and other surroundings.  [Rusting of iron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rust#Chemical_reactions) involves the formation of hydrated oxides and so requires the presence of moisture, either as water vapor or as liquid.  In a dry environment iron is indeed more resistant to corrosion because it forms anhydrous oxides which, **as long as moisture is kept away**, do provide some passivation.

Comment: So it does rust then?

Comment: Again, it depends on keeping moisture away. What we recognize as rust needs moisture, as can be seen by clicking the link.

Answer (score 2):

Pure iron is more corrosion resistant than regular steel. Also there is an alloy of iron named *wrought iron* which has very low carbon content, and that makes it more resistance to corrosion, but steel has better strength. I think also Eiffel tower was made out of wrought iron.

From the Wikipedia article about wrought iron:

> Wrought iron is an iron alloy with a very low carbon content (less than 0.08%) in contrast to that of cast iron (2.1% to 4%). It is a semi-fused mass of iron with fibrous slag inclusions (up to 2% by weight), which gives it a "grain" resembling wood that is visible when it is etched or bent to the point of failure. Wrought iron is tough, malleable, ductile, corrosion resistant, and easily welded.